# Restore Sharepoint Database - Error WSS_Content

Tags: error, restore

We are trying to restore our Sharepoint site but getting error on WSS_Content. Error is below:

> Object WSS_Content failed in event OnPostRestore. For more
>   information, see the error log located in the backup directory.
>   SPUpgradeException: The specified SPContentDatabase Name=WSS_Content
>   Parent=SPDatabaseServiceInstance Name=Microsoft##SSEE has been
>   upgraded to a newer version of SharePoint. Please upgrade this
>   SharePoint application server before attempting to access this object.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before taking a database backup from the source farm, you should make sure that

- The destination farm build number is higher or equal to the build number of source farm (Not lower than the source farm) to avoid this error.

**To find the farm build number, check**

- [Find farm patch level / latest cumulative update that has been installed on SharePoint farm](https://blog.devoworx.net/2014/11/30/find-latest-cumulative-update-installed-in-sharepoint-farm/)

**To restore a Content database backup**

- [Restore a SharePoint web application to another SharePoint farm using database attach method](https://blog.devoworx.net/2014/07/17/sql-server-backup-restore-instead-of-a-stsadm-backup-restore-in-sharepoint-2010/)

Comment: trying to find the same version of Sharepoint, which is Version 12.0.0.6690 and it comes in Sharepoint Services 3 Update MS14-22. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

This means that the version or patch level of SharePoint you're running is lower than the version the database was used with. Match the patch level the database the farm was attached to before attempting a restore.

Comment: trying to find the same version of Sharepoint, which is Version 12.0.0.6690 and it comes in Sharepoint Services 3 Update MS14-22. Any help?